# React setstate take previous values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote the below react component to handle the difficulty level of the minesweeper clone which I am making using react.

I have used radio buttons as difficulty input and would like to set the state of the component based on the selection made.

My problem is that every time I change my selection, the state is updated with my previous selection and not the current selected value. For instance, during page load the selected difficulty is ”Easy”. When I change the difficulty to say “Hard” the state still show the initial setting i.e “Easy” (I did a console log of the state to verify this).

Please help.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Difficulty extends Component{

  state = {
      height: 8,
      width: 8,
      mines: 10,
  };

  setDifficulty(event){
    let selectedDifficulty = event.target.value;
    if (selectedDifficulty === "Easy") {
        this.setState({
            height: 8,
            width: 8,
            mines: 10,
        });
    }
    if (selectedDifficulty === "Medium") {
        this.setState({
            height: 12,
            width: 12,
            mines: 20,
        });
    }
    if (selectedDifficulty === "Hard") {
        this.setState({
            height: 16,
            width: 16,
            mines: 40,
        });
    }
    this.props.updateDifficulty(this.state);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="game-difficulty">
        <div className="difficulty" onChange={this.setDifficulty.bind(this)}>
          <input type="radio" value="Easy" name="gender" defaultChecked="true" /> Easy
          <input type="radio" value="Medium" name="gender" /> Medium
          <input type="radio" value="Hard" name="gender" /> Hard
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Difficulty;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, so `this.state` will still contain the previous values if you try to use it right after calling `setState`.

You could instead do your logic that depends on `this.state` in a function given as the second argument to `setState` which will be run when the state has been updated.

```
setDifficulty(event) {
  let selectedDifficulty = event.target.value;
  let values;

  if (selectedDifficulty === "Easy") {
    values = {
      height: 8,
      width: 8,
      mines: 10
    };
  }
  if (selectedDifficulty === "Medium") {
    values = {
      height: 12,
      width: 12,
      mines: 20
    };
  }
  if (selectedDifficulty === "Hard") {
    values = {
      height: 16,
      width: 16,
      mines: 40
    };
  }

  this.setState(values, () => {
    this.props.updateDifficulty(this.state);
  });
}
```